# Iterated copy & paste VBA macro based on cell contents

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, copy-paste, iterated-function

Good Morning,

Please see the photo for context of my problem, I have also tried to start the VBA code - any help would be much appreciated! 
[My truncated data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcFrQ.png) - There is an unknown number of applications and projects.

I am trying to work out, when there might be a potential conflict in projects deploying. The criteria I'm currently working on is 28 days either side (Cell K2), this may be changed to 14 or 7 days.

My Current macro for recording 'clashes' is as follows:

```
`Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Do While i < ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

Range("B1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Copy
Range("H2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox i

End Sub'
```

I want to another macro to run within this one that where the Application is the same as the one above and there is a 'clash' in column D (this is just an =IF(AND... formula) the contents gets put in the format [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIDu2.png). This is for the first set of clashes only.

I have started to write some code, based on a previous VBA but have got stuck, any help is much appreciated.

```
`Sub clashcompile()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim i As Long


With ActiveSheet

    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastrow - 1 To 2 Step -1

        If .Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value And _
            .Cells(i + 1, "B").Value > .Cells(3, "H").Value And _
            .Cells(i + 1, "B").Value < .Cells(4, "H").Value And _
            .Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = .Cells(2, "L").Value Then'
```

I am stuck after this..

Please ask if any clarification is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this need to be VBA? it can be done by an array formula

Comment: No not necessarily, I'm not sure how to do the formula though and thought  VBA might be easier?

Comment: i cant attach an image for some reason, but i have my data in A1:b16, application A, data is column B, applications are letters A to E.  In the cells E1:E5 i have A to E, then i have an array formula F1:j5, which is this

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$16,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$16=$E1,ROW($A$1:$A$16)),COLUMNS($E$1:E$1)),1),"")

Comment: if you can msg me your email i can send you the sheet i did.